# Using bit operations influences memory consumption?

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management

I am doing a university project in Bioinformatics and have come across a really strange situation which I just don't understand.

To optimize CPU performance of a function which calculates the hash value of a sub-sequence in a bio-sequnce I replaced the following:

```
hashValue += powf(4.0, k-i-1) * PHI_function((*seqence)[startIndex + i]);
//top of file has #include<cmath>
```

with:

```
hashValue +=  (0x1 << (2*(k-i-1))) * PHI_function((*seqence)[startIndex + i]);
//top of file does not have #include<cmath> since powf is not used
```

Variable explanation:

```
//k is the sub-sequence length
//i is a index going from 0 to k
//sequence -> pointer to bio-sequence string 
//hashValue is of type int
//
//PHI_function has the following signature: inline int HashTableCalculationMethod::PHI_function(char b)
// and only conatins: return (b & 0x6) >> 1; 
//which means
// if (b == 'A') {
//     return 0;
// } else if (b == 'C') {
//     return 1;
// } else if (b == 'G') {
//     return 2;
// } else if (b == 'T') {
//     return 3;
// }
```

This improved the program time performance by ~5 times, but for some reason also increased the memory consumption from ~4GB to ~7.5GB (when running on a sample I received for the project).

I am sure this is the change which influenced the memory consumptions because of Git version tracking (I have commits before and after the modification).

Can someone explain how this is influencing the program memory consumption?

Project is available at [link](https://github.com/pa1511/Bioinformatics). Commit which changes the performance is d39d055

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it's the culprit? Seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes I am. That is the only thing that changed between two commits and I have no idea how that can influence memory.

Comment: Do not post screenshots.

Comment: @NeilButterworth sorry, I didn't know it wasn't allowed. I removed it.

Comment: Perhaps the new version has fewer hash collisions and therefore requires more buckets? Although that would be a huge change from changing the hash value.

Comment: If the value of `2*(k-i-1)` is greater than or equal to the number of bits in an `unsigned` on your target platform, your change causes the program to have undefined behaviour.    Compilers (optimisers) can cause code to have many strange effects when behaviour is undefined.    In any event, you haven't given enough information - such as return type of `PHI_value()`, or the range of values it can return.

Comment: @Peter the maximum k value which can occur is 15 so that should fit into int

Comment: @SoronelHaetir If I am not mistaken the new and the old value should calculate the same value so I don't see how that influences hash collisions

Comment: @Peter I added a description about the PHI_function in the question

Comment: Put both lines in the code with an assert to check they always give the same value.

Comment: @RichardCritten you are right they don't always produce the same value. So that must be influencing bucketing because the value is later used in a map. 
Thank you very much :)

Comment: The only thing coming to me off the top of my head to explain the memory difference is single-precision floating-point flooring/truncation when you cast to int. The first version might actually be losing precision in ways that is incorrectly yielding a smaller result than it is supposed to give.

Comment: @TeamUpvote you are right and I found that out by asserting as Richard Critten suggested. But since his answer is in a comment like this I don't know how to accept it to close the question

Comment: You could answer it yourself and accept it or accept L. Serni's. He seemed to have a hunch that it had to do with the casting. If you answer yourself, it might be handy to give a detailed answer of the problem and how you solved it for others to see if they encounter a similar situation. Cheers!

Comment: BTW, for future ref, watch out for those issues casting from float to int. Rounding will generally give you the desired results in such cases, like this: `int int_val = static_cast<int>(flt_val + 0.5f);` That way if you have like `15.9998f`, it'll still get rounded to `16`. BTW, do you guys like tactical RPGs? Also I wanna up-vote all this stuff but I ran outta up-votes! I will up-vote later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can really see only two options.

Apparently, your code still does the same thing as before - 4<sup>k-i-1</sup> is always the same number no matter how you calculate it. Or is it? The new calculation yields an integer, and you multiply it by Phi. Is it possible that this results in the Phi value being cast to an integer for multiplication purposes? (Seems unlikely, but try casting the `(1<<...)` to double just to see). If the value is not interpreted the same, then this may influence the number of collisions in the hash table, and therefore the memory.

A variation on the above is that `(1 << (2*(k-i-1)))` has not the same range of `powf()` because of data type limitations; you should check the maximum possible value depending on k. It should be the case that `k-i-1` is always positive or zero, and always below 31 (or is it 30?), or 63 depending on integer size.

You can however **precalculate** powf. This gives you the best of both worlds: fast calculation and certainly correct results. If the index is always positive, before in the initialization you run

```
// vector of doubles. All copacetic as long as
// maxValue... is correctly estimated. Otherwise,
// "hello, undefined behaviour".
for (x = 0; x <= maxValueForKMinusIMinusOne; x++) {
    powfTable[x] = powf(4.0, x);
}
```

and in the kernel calculation you replace `powf(4.0, k - i - 1)` with `powfTable[k-i-1]`. **You can do this with any function call with reasonably limited effective domain**. Here, I guess you can't have more than, what, seventy values?

If it's not that, you could be mistaken in a previous commit, the one where the minimizer vector was made common between calls. I couldn't follow the code, but *might* this result in the single vector growing larger than it should - sort of a reverse Jordan representation? You wouldn't notice it in unit tests, and this *might* lead you to believe that the change changed nothing - until you run the code on a larger set.

Comment: I tried with the following cast: ((double)(0x1 << (2*(k-i-1))))
and the memory again grows to ~7.5GB

Comment: As for the common vector I make sure to call clear on it between calls so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: @Richard Critten suggested I put an assert and make sure both versions always produce the same value. They don't which then influences hash bucket collisions.